# gsutil setwebcfg weird sub folder behavior

Tags: google-cloud-storage

It seems google cloud storage provides a different behavior whether a folder is access from a web client with or without a trailing /

A simple test shows a different behavior for the following link

- http://gstest.tekartik.com/sub/dir (fail to load css - background is white)
- http://gstest.tekartik.com/sub/dir/ (works ok - background is black)

Where the bucket has been configured using:

`gsutil setwebcfg -m index.html -e 404.html gs://gstest.tekartik.com`

For information it contains 3 simple files index.html/404.html/style.css where style.css only set the background to black.
They both correctly "redirect" to the url http://gstest.tekartik.com/sub/dir/index.html. However the relative path does not allow for style.css to be loaded properly in the first case.

What I would like is to have the 1st case to be redirected using a trailing / (which is what Amazon S3 does). What is needed for this to work propertly so that I can give a url to someone without worrying about whether the trailing / is entered?

as a side, this works fine as at the root level (http://gstest.tekartik.com/ got automatically renamed to http://gstest.tekartik.com as here the trailing / is not needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spoken with the engineering team and we agree this should work the way you expected. This will be fixed in the near term by adding a bucket configuration setting to enable the expected behavior (the extra config step is needed to avoid breaking any apps depending on the current behavior). We're also planning to make it easy to update the new config setting via gsutil. I can't say when exactly these changes will be available but tune into the [gs-announce group](https://groups.google.com/group/gs-announce) to monitor these (and other) details about Google Cloud Storage. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Update (June 3, 2013): This has now been fixed in production.

Comment: Taken from an NAA of @Tom: `Marc Cohen, I have a similar setup to this and was wondering if it is possible for you to set up the redirect from 'dir' to 'dir/' because as you can see with the sample URLs here the 'dir' path will show the index.html in the URL path but the 'dir/' does not (which is preferable). Thanks`